# How to call MainActivity method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call method share() from a fragment. share() is in MainActivity.java

```
Button shareButton = new Button(getActivity());
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
      ma.share();              //Doesn't work! NullPointerException
   }
}
```

share():

```
public void share() {
     Intent i = new Intent();
     i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     i.setType("text/plain");
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareString);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Say Something"));
}
```

Comment: ((MainActivity) context).share(v);

Comment: Whats the use of View V in your share function? Post your logcat

Comment: before that just declare 'private MainActivity context; '

Comment: MainActivity is the name given to the class launched from your Manifest Launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
```

To

```
MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

`getActivity()` returns an instance of `Activity` so it must be cast

Comment: getActivity() returns FragmentActivity (since I'm trying to call from a fragment.

Comment: Fragment and FragmentActivity are not the same thing. getActivity() will return parent activity of a Fragment.

Comment: Apologies, yes you just need to cast the Activity returned from getActivity() as your MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

For example change this:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
```

To this:

```
MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

((MainActivity) getActivity()).methodName this will help you, try it

Answer (score 0):

from software engineering Design principles

```
public class Utils {
    public static void share(Context context,String shareString) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareString);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "#CrystalMaths"));

    }
}
```

and wherever you are use

```
Utils.share(getApplicationContext(),"share this line");
```

this makes our code reusable and cohesive

Comment: Please fix the class name so it obeys JavaBeans naming convetions.

Comment: thanks @Gabriel, done. but why you didn't make that edit and won +2 reputation

Comment: Because I would need to change at least 6 characters to edit and there were only 2.

Comment: simply you can add invisible code comment `<!--hello world -->`